# How to hide third element td?

Tags: html, css

I have the following table:

```
<table id="test">
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I need to hide third element `td` using CSS.

As the result I need something like the following HTML:

```
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I hide the third `td` in every row?

In tag element not add class or id - need to hide using only CSS.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
#test tr td:nth-child(3n+3) {
    display: none;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMsgV/1)

Comment: +1 this is fast ... just start writing and see 3 more answer :D

Comment: it fast than `#test tr td:nth-child(3) { display:none; }` ?
if yes, that why ?

Comment: 3n+3 will hide every third element. 3 will hide only the third element.

Answer (score 9):

```
#test tr td:nth-child(3) { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not target the third element with css if you do not have an ID or a Class to target specifically.

You could use jQuery to do this.

The answers provided by other users (using nth child) did not disclose the fact that the code is not cross browser compatible. IE <9 can not see the selector.